# Pandas aggregation subtraction based on column value

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Suppose I have DataFrame

```
'name'     'quantity'   'day'
'A'         1           'Monday'
'A'         10          'Sunday'
'A'         5           'Friday'
'B'         2           'Monday'
'B'         30          'Sunday'
'B'         5           'Thursday'
```

What I need to build is another dataframe where for each *name* I subtract the quantity of Monday from the quantity of Sunday. So, I guess I need a `groupBy` on the *name* and then an `agg` with a function, but I am not sure how to do the filter so that only those days are considered.

Following the example, the end result I seek is

```
'name'     'sub_quantity'
'A'         9 
'B'         28
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***setup***

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

txt = """name     quantity   day
A         1           Monday
A         10          Sunday
A         5           Friday
B         2           Monday
B         30          Sunday
B         5           Thursday"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), delim_whitespace=True)
```

***option 1***
`unstack`

```
d1 = df.set_index(['name', 'day']).quantity.unstack()

d1.Sunday.sub(d1.Monday)

name
A     9.0
B    28.0
dtype: float64
```

***option 2***
`query`

```
s = df.set_index('name').query('day == "Sunday"').quantity
m = df.set_index('name').query('day == "Monday"').quantity
s - m

name
A     9
B    28
Name: quantity, dtype: int64
```

***option 3***
`xs`

```
d1 = df.set_index(['day', 'name']).quantity
d1.xs('Sunday') - d1.xs('Monday')

name
A     9
B    28
Name: quantity, dtype: int64
```

***option 4***
cute `apply`

```
def obnoxious(x):
    s = x.day.eq('Sunday').idxmax()
    m = x.day.eq('Monday').idxmax()
    q = 'quantity'
    return x.get_value(s, q) - x.get_value(m, q)

df.groupby('name').apply(obnoxious)

name
A     9
B    28
dtype: int64
```

---

---

***timing***
example data
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Solution with [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) and substracting by [`sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sub.html):

```
df = pd.pivot(index=df.name, columns=df.day, values=df.quantity)
print (df.Sunday.sub(df.Monday).reset_index(name='sub_quantity'))
  name  sub_quantity
0    A           9.0
1    B          28.0
```